# In P&ID, what is the difference in terms of information between pipe and signal line In the diagram?

Tags: instrumentation, pi-diagram

I got a question. In the P&ID, the pipe will have information such as size, spec, service, insulation size/type and etc. For signal line, is it necessary to have these kind of information? or they just a graphic representation with no information?

Answer (score 4):

It may be dependent on the industry, but in my experience that type of information is not included on a P&ID for instrumentation lines.  Instead, there is an Instrumentation Installation Specification which defines the requirements for these lines, including material, size, routing, type and location of valves, etc.

Comment: I see, so not all information is compulsory to be in the P&ID especially the instrumentation lines. Thank you for your sharing sir.